# flutter - Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host,

Tags: flutter, error-handling, socketexception

This is the error:

```
E/flutter (18597): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: No route to host
E/flutter (18597): #0      UserService.existsByPhone (package:bridge/services/user/user_service.dart:79:7)
E/flutter (18597): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18597): #1      _AuthStore.existsByPhone (package:bridge/store/auth/auth_store.dart:65:24)
E/flutter (18597): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18597): #2      AsyncAction.run (package:mobx/src/api/async/async_action.dart:28:14)
E/flutter (18597): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18597): #3      _PhoneNumberCheckState._checkPhone (package:bridge/widgets/auth/phone_number_check.dart:199:31)
E/flutter (18597): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18597): #4      _PhoneNumberCheckState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:bridge/widgets/auth/phone_number_check.dart:148:23)
E/flutter (18597): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18597):
```

I run my application using localhost and my real mobile device connect in WIFI and pc connect by cable. i did check the ip address `(192.168.1.4)` but the error continue.

My backend is `Quarkus (Java)` and the app is `Flutter`.

I already added in my manifest, but error continue:

Comment: Check the firewall settings for your PC to allow external devices?

Comment: I'm using linux and I try with ufw, but still it's not working.